# Vtune throws aps error while running MPI samples

Tags: mpi, intel, intel-vtune, intel-oneapi

I am trying to profile my MPI application using Intel Vtune. While trying to run the below two commands, I am getting error.

1. I_MPI_DEBUG=5.
   I tried two things,

1. export I_MPI_DEBUG = 5
   mpirun -np 4 aps ~/binary/vasp_std_2022
2. mpirun -genv I_MPI_DEBUG=5 -np 4 aps ~/binary/vasp_std_2022

vtune: Warning: Memory bandwidth collection is not supported inside a virtual machine since uncore events cannot be collected. For full functionality, consider using a bare-metal environment.
vtune: Warning: CPU frequency data collection is not supported on this platform.
vtune: Error: amplxe-perf:
Using CPUID GenuineIntel-6-6A-6
both cgroup and no-aggregation modes only available in system-wide mode
Usage: perf stat [] []
-G, --cgroup monitor event in cgroup name only
-A, --no-aggr disable CPU count aggregation
-a, --all-cpus system-wide collection from all CPUs
--for-each-cgroup expand events for each cgroup
vtune: Error: Preliminary validation of the requested events failed.
aps Error: Cannot run the collection.
aps Error: Cannot process configs directory.
aps Error: Cannot process configs directory.
aps Error: Cannot process configs directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command you are using 'aps' while profiling.

If you are using aps command you need to use some parameters like collection-mode as `--collection-mode=<mode>`
This parameter is used to specify a comma separated list of data to collect. Possible values:

- hwc : hardware counters
- omp : openMP statistics
- mpi : MPI statistcs
- all : all possible data(default)

Try to use the command as below

```
mpirun -genv I_MPI_DEBUG= 5 -np 4 aps --collect-mode=omp ./obj
```

[image]